# One Infopath Form that displays data from Two Lists

Tags: infopath

I have two SharePoint Lists.  My primary list consists of Field Names with their definitions.  My secondary list consists of all the values and the value's definition for the field on my primary list with a look up column to the ID for the primary list.  My intention is that when the user clicks on the Field Name from the primary list, that I could populate the values associated with that field from my secondary list on one Infopath form.  I have yet to figure this out.  When I add the secondary source to the Infopath form, it brings back every value on the secondary list and not just the values associated with the ID on the first list.

Comment: Is it like a mapping in your second list. Example Field1-Value1,alue2; Field2-Value1, Value2. On InfoPath form, you need to get value1 and value 2 for field 1. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to apply the filter (rule) for the secondary list lookup ID.

It can be done by following steps (high level) :

- Add rule for the property and select set field value
- In the rule detail you have to select the field value (destination)
- In the value field, you have to map the source and destination lookup field values to apply the filter like below :

---

```
xdXDocument:GetDOM("DatasourceName")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Engagement_x0020_PMM/pc:Person/pc:AccountId[../../../d:PMOPMM/pc:Person/pc:AccountId = xdXDocument:get-DOM()/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/my:SharePointListItem_RW/my:Portfolio_x0020_PMM_x0020__x0028/pc:Person/pc:AccountId]
```

Comment: Yes, map all the require fields